# Typeclass constraint of different kind

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-constraints

I have been fiddling with general type classes for lists in Haskell.

```
class HasEmpty a where
  empty :: a
  isEmpty :: a -> Bool

class HasEmpty (l a) => List l where
  cons :: a -> l a -> l a
  uncons :: l a -> (a, l a)
```

To give you an idea of how it might work, here are instances for `[]`:

```
instance HasEmpty [a] where
  empty = []
  isEmpty [] = True
  isEmpty _  = False

instance List [] where
  cons = (:)
  uncons (x:xs) = (x,xs)
```

However, this raises an error:

```
Not in scope: type variable 'a'
```

This is caused by the constraint `HasEmpty (l a)`. I am not desperately interested in this particular example, but I am interested in the concept in general. `HasEmpty` is a class for types of kind `*`, while `List` is a class for types of kind `* -> *`. **Is it possible for me to make a typeclass constraint of a different kind than the typeclass it is constraining?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any case you can always express underlying logic either using multiparameter typeclasses (as in fact it is done in [ListLike](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ListLike/3.1.2/doc/html/Data-ListLike.html#t%3aListLike)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

class HasEmpty a where
  empty :: a
  isEmpty :: a -> Bool

class HasEmpty (l a) => List l a where
  cons :: a -> l a -> l a
  uncons :: l a -> (a, l a)


instance HasEmpty [a] where
  empty = []
  isEmpty [] = True
  isEmpty _  = False

instance List [] a where
  cons = (:)
  uncons (x:xs) = (x,xs)
```

Or more elegantly via type families:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class HasEmpty a where
  empty :: a
  isEmpty :: a -> Bool


class HasEmpty a => List a where
  type Elem a :: *
  cons :: Elem a -> a -> a
  uncons :: a -> (Elem a, a)


instance HasEmpty [a] where
  empty = []
  isEmpty [] = True
  isEmpty _  = False


instance List [a] where
  type Elem [a] = a
  cons = (:)
  uncons (x:xs) = (x,xs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. E.g. this will work fine for the same two classes:

```
class HasEmpty (l ()) => List l where
  cons :: a -> l a -> l a
  uncons :: l a -> (a, l a)
```

or (where `List1 :: (* -> *) -> * -> *`)

```
class HasEmpty1 (l a) => List1 l a where
  cons :: a -> l a -> l a
  uncons :: l a -> (a, l a)
```

What you can't do is add new variables in constraints.

Comment: Which probably prevents you from doing what you want.  knowing `HasEmpty (l ())` is not that helpful when you are talking about general `l a`s

Comment: Right, what he really wants is `class (forall a. HasEmpty (l a)) => ...`, which isn't allowed (and I don't think can be reasonably added). But the second option may be more workable.

Comment: Might want to add a fundep `l -> a` in there. Not sure.